# Adding up Double Gamma distributions to obtain new Double Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to compute the average distribution of two Double Gamma distributions to obtain a new Double Gamma distribution. I don't know if this is possible, however.

I tried the following. Given two $\Gamma$ distributions parametrized by $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we want to obtain the average of these 2 distributions in closed form. Let $\Gamma \Gamma$ denote the double gamma distribution. What I tried:

$$\Gamma \Gamma (x; \alpha) = \frac{1}{2 \Gamma(\alpha)} |x|^{\alpha-1}e^{-|x|}$$

Adding up  two distributions of this type and normalizing we obtain:

$$\frac{1}{4 \Gamma(\alpha)} |x|^{\alpha-1}e^{-|x|} + \frac{1}{4 \Gamma(\beta)} |x|^{\beta-1}e^{-|x|} = \frac{1}{4 \Gamma(\alpha)}e^{-|x|} |x|^{\alpha-1}(1 +\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)} |x|^{\beta - \alpha})$$

Now, this is where I am stuck. I want to get this into the form:

$$\Gamma \Gamma (x; \gamma) = \frac{1}{2 \Gamma(\gamma)} |x|^{\gamma-1}e^{-|x|}$$

where $\gamma = f(\alpha, \beta)$. Is this possible at all? What would be a good alternative to approximation to take an average of the two distribution if this is impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the intended purpose of adding up two PDFs in this manner? You're trying to add the PDFs and not determine the PDF of the sum of two DG random variables right?

Comment: And I believe the expoenntial terms should be $e^{-|x|}$ not $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Hi @AaronHendrickson. Thanks for the comment. It is a very specific scenario. I have samples from something approximating these distributions. So say samples from one with param $\alpha$, and another set of samples of a distribution with parameter $\beta$. Now from the "merge" of these samples I only want to pick the outliers (say N of them). Thus, getting the combined PDF let's me decide what samples to pick so I only get the outliers of the combined probability distribution. In my case I can't just make one big array because this would be very slow, as this would require both merge and sort.